# Data not displayed on recycler view

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, adapter, notifydatasetchanged

I have a recycler view issue where the data is not being displayed. onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder are not being called. When I call notifyDataSetChanged(), notifyChanged() is called but mObservers is empty, so it won't update my list.

```
public void notifyChanged() {
        
        for (int i = mObservers.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            mObservers.get(i).onChanged();
        }
}
```

here's my adapter code:

```
class ReleasesAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ReleasesAdapter.ReleasesViewHolder>() {

    private val data = mutableListOf<Album>(Album())

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ReleasesViewHolder {
        return ReleasesViewHolder(
            LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.song_item, parent, false)
        )
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ReleasesViewHolder, position: Int) {
       holder.bindView(data[position])
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return data.size
    }

    fun setItems(items: List<Album>) {
        data.addAll(items)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    inner class ReleasesViewHolder(
        override val containerView: View
    ) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(containerView), LayoutContainer {

        fun bindView(item: Album) {
           containerView.nameTv.text = item.name
        }
    }
}
```

And here's my activity code:

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), Contract.View {

@Inject
lateinit var presenter: Contract.Presenter

private val releasesAdapter = ReleasesAdapter()

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    resultsRv.run {
        adapter = releasesAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
    }

    presenter.loadNewReleases()
}

override fun showReleases(data: List<Album>) {
    releasesAdapter.setItems(data)
}

override fun showErrorMessage(message: String) {

}
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".presentation.MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/resultsRv"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:listitem="@layout/song_item" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

song_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/nameTv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/song_item_margin"
    android:textColor="@color/black" />
```

Please send help :(

Edit: Added Xml code

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using the scope functions wrong especially `run` in this case. Use `run()` function if you need to compute some value or want to limit the scope of multiple local variables.

So while your other code seems okay, I believe your Adapter and LayoutManager is not being assigned. I would suggest you replace the `run` with `apply` and try again.

```kotlin
resultsRv.apply {
        adapter = releasesAdapter
        layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this@MainActivity)
   }
```

Comment: apply is better in this case but that is not the issue. Changed and still there.

Comment: @marcia Could you paste your XML code? There is nothing wrong with the code as I said as such. Even better to debug it somewhat, try sending some dummy data just and see if that shows up?

Comment: @marcia Your XML is fine as well. Try loading up some dummy data. Just some dummy of your `Album` class and call `releaseAdapter.setItem()` with that dummy data. We might need to debug it step by step I believe.

Comment: Added a dummy list inside onCreate and it worked. 
However, if I move this code https://gist.github.com/marcia-rocha/cb7712e108ac6cb4f7229ddd44746920 to inside showReleases I get a NPE https://gist.github.com/marcia-rocha/7c143408a1646a88ae7c70d4851abf27

Comment: @marcia I just checked your gists. We are having an issue with the `context`. As clarified from dummy data there is no problem with our `recyclerView`. You might want to check into your Presenter logic next and especially see what is the `Context` being used as pointed out in this error `Context.getApplicationInfo() on a null`

Comment: Thank you. I have never had this issue before. I will take a look at my presenter and check my DI modules

Comment: Yes, sure. I can't comment on it without your code but most likely I don't think in your `showReleases` anything is coming up and thus nothing is being displayed. Might want to check for empty data there.

Comment: It is not empty, I checked. But I get a NPE if I try to access resultsRv so something is not right :(

Comment: May I ask what are you using to access views @marcia. It does not seem like `ViewBinding`. I would suggest you to go old-school with `findViewById` and then try again.

Comment: Synthetics at first but changed to view binding. The problem was with my di. I will provide the repo later :) Many thanks for your help!